# SpringFramework: expected single matching bean but found 2

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-mvc

I'm building a project read data from MongoDB using SpringFramework, with structure for **Repository** and **Service** as below:

```
Repository:
    + Interfaces: 
        - I <T extends Object>
        - I1 extends I<M1>
        - I2 extends I<M2>
    + Implements: 
        - RI Abstract RI<T extends Object>
        - RI1 extends RI<M1> implements I1
        - RI2 extends RI<M2> implements I2

Service:
    + Interfaces: 
        - SI <T extends Object>
        - SI1 extends SI<M1>
        - SI2 extends SI<M1>
    + Implements:
        - Abstract SIIMPL : @Autowired I<?>
        - SI1IMPL : extends SIIMPL<M1> implements SI1
        - SI2IMPL : extends SIIMPL<M2> implements SI2
```

When I running, it throw an exception:

> No qualifying bean of type 'I' available: expected single matching
>   bean but found 2: I1,I2

When I delete RI2, it work properly. In my opinion, I think the root cause is the @Autowired from Abstract(SIIMPL) to another abstract(I) that have
2 implements are RI1 and RI2 so spring does not know what bean to pick.

If someone have any idea, please leave me a comment. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly you should use a generics not wildcarding in the Abstract SIIMPL class. So that it looks like:

```
public abstract class SIIMPL<T> {

   protected I<T> foo; // Don't autowire here

}
```

Then as above don't autowire the generic I object into the abstract class just define it there and then autowire it into your concrete classes via constuctor injection:

```
public class SI1IMPL extends SIIMPL<M1> implements ST1 {

  public ST1IMPL(@Autowired I<M1> foo) {
      this.foo = foo;
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It really help !

Comment: No problem, glad I could help :)