# JpaRepository of abstract @MappedSuperclass without @Id

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have an abstract entity annotated with `@MappedSuperclass`:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity {
    public abstract T getId();
    public abstract void setId(T id);
}
```

Then I inherit my Entities from it, defining their id in each one:

```
@Entity
public class EntityA {
  @Id
  private int id;
  // ....
}

@Entity
public class EntityB {
  @Id
  private long id;
  // ....
}
```

Now I want to create a generic JpaRepository that accepts any class that extends from my Base Entity:

```
public interface BaseRepository<T extends BaseEntity, ID extends Serializable> extends JpaRepository<T, ID> {
}
```

But Spring trows an exception saying `BaseEntity` has no ID:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: This class [BaseEntity] does not define an IdClass
```

**Please, check Plog's comments in his answer**. I could solve it injecting each repository type in service's contructor

Comment: The is precisely the point: being able to have different id fields in child entities

Comment: This is completely generic idea

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I know you can't make generic repositories like this. You will need to make an individual repository for each of your <s>concrete entity classes.</s> aggregate roots (thanks @JensSchauder).

You can however make a generic base repository that can define some common queries between these two repositories by marking it as a @NoRepositoryBean:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface BaseRepository<T extends BaseEntity, ID extends Serializable> extends JpaRepository<T, ID> {
  //common methods
}
```

Your concrete class repositories should then extend this instead of JpaRepository:

```
public interface EntityARepository extends BaseRepository<EntityA, Integer> {
}
```

Comment: One minor complaint: You don't make a repository for each concrete entity class, but for each Aggregate Root. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/38542469/66686

Comment: But I need that generic repository, because I want to create a generic service with the generic repo autowired so that Spring automatically injects the repo for the corresponding entity

Comment: @gmc I'm not sure how that would work. Would you have two concrete services that extend the generic service?

Comment: Exactly. If I had all my entities having similar PKs I had it working, but I have 3 kinds of PKs: Long id, Long other_name and composite. I'm trying to make it all generic, but Its hard to account for such heterogeneity

Comment: @gmc You can define the `@NoRepositoryBean` BaseRepository as a property of your BaseService but don't autowire it in. Instead autowire the specific repository to each concrete service via constructor injection. Similar to my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47201009/springframework-expected-single-matching-bean-but-found-2/47201232#47201232

Comment: Seems like a good idea ... I'm gonna give it a try, I'll let you know. Thanks anyway

Comment: Hey @Plog, it's working. I love you. I'm marking your answer as correct and referring to the comments. Thank you so much

Comment: No problem. Im glad I could help :) good luck with the rest of your project.